# Binding .inputrc on Mac?

Tags: mac, command-line, terminal.app, inputrc

On Linux I had this line on my .inputrc:

```
"\C-/": undo
```

which doesn't work on Mac. Is there a way to make it work?

On another note, is there a way to bind command keys on inputrc?